# Can you calculate internal resistance of battery by shorting it?

Tags: ohms-law, internal-resistance

Can I measure the current of a battery by shorting the circuit and by ohms-law divide the voltage of the battery by the current measured to get internal resistance?

Comment: You can't get the current without providing a resistance for voltage to drop over, at which point you may as well just get the voltage drop with a reasonable resistance and do that math instead.

Comment: I’m sorry if I’m so wrong as this is not my field of studies, but doesn’t voltage drop over the internal resistance as well?

Comment: Yes, proportional to the ratio created by the potential divider created by the two resistances.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you can’t get the current without using additional resistors? If I short the circuit, doesn’t that mean that the current I’m measuring is running through the internal resistance? And therefore I would be able to calculate that internal resistance given the current I measured and the voltage of the battery. Unless of course the meter will READ the wrong current running on the internal resistance somehow?

Comment: Current is calculated by measuring the voltage drop across a known resistance.

Comment: Or maybe I’m wrong, since I have no idea about potential dividers yet, I’m just trying to understand things solely on my knowledge of ohms-law. If ohms-law is not enough to explain my confusion, then I might have to read on potential dividers first D:

Comment: Potential dividers are an application of Ohm's Law, and you should understand them as well.

Comment: Are you implying that you can’t measure the current through the internal resistance with a meter, if there is no other external known resistance ?

Comment: If that’s the case; then what kind of current am I measuring with a multimeter when I short the battery?

Comment: If you're using a meter to measure current then the resistance is inside the meter, and is [affecting your measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter#Burden_voltage).

Comment: I know how to calculate the internal resistance with an external resistor like you suggest, I’m just trying to understand why I can’t calculate the internal resistance by just shorting the battery and using a multimeter to get the current going through the internal resistance

Comment: Basically implying that measuring the current using a meter is not accurate unless it’s an ideal meter. And it’s more accurate to measure the voltage drops instead using an external resistor! I understand it now, thank you

Comment: @AznBoyStride Some batteries will slightly get heated up to the extent one can't touch.. Some batteries may just silently explode, if somebody shorts the battery directly. Assuming everything is safe, still it is impossible to measure the internal resistance with a short across it. Only thing you can measure is current which certainly varies heavily over time for a short

Comment: I understand things a lot more now! One quick small question: is it still impossible to measure given an perfect meter and perfecf battery? ( which does not exists )

Comment: it depends on the battery and the meter if you can measure the short circuit current, if the battery is an AA alkaline and the meter doesn't have a fuse on the 10A range, you might be lucky.  also short circuit current may not be representative of the resistance of the battery at lower currents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to direct you here
[BU-902: How to Measure Internal Resistance](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_internal_resistance)

For a quick idea, measuring open circuit voltage and again with a suitable load (so that battery's internal resistance will be comparable in ration with this load) should give an idea of internal resistance.

With the load, the voltage read will be less than 1.5 V. Say, it is 1.3 V. Then the remaining 0.2 V is dropped somewhere other than the load. The drop will be across internal resistance of the battery.

You know the load resistance value(Rload), supply value (1.5V) and drop across load that is 1.3 V. Internal resistance can be calculated easily.

[image]

Please take care of wattage of resistors being used and the allowed safe limit of current of the battery.

Comment: http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/voltage-divider-calculator may come handy.. You just need ohms law alone to solve

Comment: However, and this is important, the internal resistance is not ohmic, in the sense that it does not apply a single value across a broad range of voltages and currents. Internal resistance, as measured here, varies with current, state of charge and age of battery. Not to mention, of course, battery chemistry and construction.

Comment: Generally internal resistance will also increase with time if the load is heavy due to "polarization". This is because the electro-chemical reaction slows.